# How to convert a E notation string to a float with fixed exponent in python

Tags: python, scientific-notation, format-specifiers, mantissa

My instrumentation device returns strings of data such as 2.89E-6, 9.87E-1, 4.18E-4 etc.

How can I change the representation such that the exponent is always -3. My intention is to manually extract the Mantissa of the resultant expression.

**Desired output:**

string `2.89E-6` becomes-> float `0.00289E-3`

string `9.87E-1` becomes-> float `987E-3`

string `4.18E-4` becomes-> float `0.418E-3`

Eventually, would like to extract the mantissa-> 0.000289, 987, 0.418 respectively as my “final” output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module for manipulation of decimal numbers, then convert to `float` at the end if needed.

```
import decimal

data = ['2.89E-6', '9.87E-1', '4.18E-4']

for s in data:
    n = decimal.Decimal(s)
    print(float(n * 1000))
```

Output:

```
0.00289
987.0
0.418
```